# How to Place the Right Seams for UV Unwrapping

Tags: texturing, uv

Where can I read how UV Maps should look and how to know where to place the seams? Here I have a very simple model I'd like you to suggest where the seams should be placed and why. I have attached a picture of my test model and attached the Blend file.

[Blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33445)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion you should try to place the seams in that way, so the *UV islands* in *UV/Image Editor* are even distributed and have a proper scale that reflects the scale of the model's elements. It is often the matter of experimenting. You should think of it as it was a real model. Try to imagine how you may cut it open with scissors and spread on a flat surface. 
[image]

The example below shows how the different unwrap of the same object results in less uniform Uv islands distribution, which is less beneficial.
[image]

Here is the .blend with the seams placed: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33446

Answer (score 2):

You could read here for uv mapping, how and where with examples http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Unwrapping
The link will help you understand the information need on mapping types, unwrapping and marking seams.
I personally would recommend seaming near the middle.

Comment: When writing questions or answers it is recommended that the said question or answer be sufficient to clearly ask or answer the question without any outside sources, as links to other sites may become obsolete or broken over time.

Comment: Sorry I just placed it down from him asking "where can I read"