# How can I UV Unwrap a Minecraft box model?

Tags: uv

I'm trying to create the character from game Minecraft. It's simple and I finished it. Now I want to unwrap it like its texture file:

[image]

As you can see it's small (on size too) and it's box styled too. But when I try to unwrap for example face, I get a circular output... How can I unwrap my model like that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to ***mark seams*** to create the unwrap like this. Select the edges you want to place seams on, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>-->*Mark Seam*. For more tips about how to place seams right see: [How to Place the Right Seams for UV Unwrapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21164/how-to-place-the-right-seams-for-uv-unwrapping). After placing seams to one side of your mesh *apply* the *Mirror modifier*. Alternatively you may start from *appying* it and then ***mark seams***.
[image]

Next select the whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>) and press <kbd>U</kbd>-->*Unwrap*. As you can see you get the result similar to the one you provided. If you want to make it identical you have to experiment with seams placement.
[image]

Here's the .blend with my seams placement example: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Smart uv project would work quite well for this.

[image]

You can also adjust the island packing quite easily like this:

[image]

As a side note, you'll want to get rid of those verts in the middle of the object.

Here is my blend:

[image]

(As for unwrapping to the image, I think it would be far more difficult than just repainting as it's only a few pixels anyway...)